# Repeated interactions between partners (dyads)

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

In this research, speakers and recipients (dyads) interact with each other in written communication, where recipients are those who respond to what the speakers said (the speaker opens up the thread).

For your reference, the data are in a form of:

```
structure(list(topic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), thread = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), speaker_id = c(111, 111, 333, 
222, 222, 222, 111, 111, 777, 111, 111), recipient_id = c(222, 
333, 111, 111, 555, 444, 222, 777, 111, 333, 777), dyad = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("111_222", 
"111_333", "111_777", "222_444", "222_555"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), codepage = 51949L)
```

I wanted to ask for your advice regarding 3 variables:

1. **"Repeated" interaction (Y/N)**: A "repeated" interaction refers to an interaction where the partners took a turn; for instance, it occurs when a speaker responds to what the recipient responded to the speaker. This variable would be binary; 0 (no repeated interaction), 1 (repeated interaction).
2. **"Repeated" interaction (2) (order)**: If the repeated interaction occurred for a given observation (row), what is the order of the repeated interaction?
3. **Total interactions**: Irrespective of repeated interaction, how many interactions where there within a thread?

The final results would look like:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ topic ║ thread ║ speaker ║ recipient ║   dyad  ║   repeated  ║    repeated    ║     total    ║
║       ║        ║    id   ║     id    ║         ║ interaction ║ interaction(2) ║ interactions ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║    (Y/N)    ║     (order)    ║    (count)   ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    222    ║ 111_222 ║      0      ║        0       ║       1      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    333    ║ 111_333 ║      0      ║        0       ║       2      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   333   ║    111    ║ 111_333 ║      1      ║        1       ║       2      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    111    ║ 111_222 ║      0      ║        0       ║       1      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    555    ║ 222_555 ║      0      ║        0       ║       1      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    444    ║ 222_444 ║      0      ║        0       ║       1      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    222    ║ 111_222 ║      0      ║        0       ║       1      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    777    ║ 111_777 ║      0      ║        0       ║       3      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2.00  ║    3   ║   777   ║    111    ║ 111_777 ║      1      ║        1       ║       3      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2.00  ║    3   ║   111   ║    333    ║ 111_333 ║      0      ║        0       ║       1      ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    777    ║ 111_777 ║      1      ║        2       ║       3      ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

The final results with explanations are:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ topic ║ thread ║ speaker ║ recipient ║   dyad  ║   repeated  ║         explanation         ║    repeated   ║        explanation       ║     total    ║          explanation         ║
║       ║        ║    id   ║     id    ║         ║ interaction ║                             ║ interaction 2 ║                          ║ interactions ║                              ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║    (Y/N)    ║                             ║    (order)    ║                          ║    (count)   ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    222    ║ 111_222 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       1      ║ Here, the very first         ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║                             ║               ║                          ║              ║ interaction is counted       ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   111   ║    333    ║ 111_333 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       2      ║ In total, 111 and 333 had    ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║                             ║               ║                          ║              ║ 2 interactions in the thread ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    1   ║   333   ║    111    ║ 111_333 ║      1      ║ This is where the repeated  ║       1       ║                          ║       2      ║                              ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║ interaction b/w 111 and 333 ║               ║                          ║              ║                              ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║ happened                    ║               ║                          ║              ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    111    ║ 111_222 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       1      ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    555    ║ 222_555 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       1      ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  1.00 ║    2   ║   222   ║    444    ║ 222_444 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       1      ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    222    ║ 111_222 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       1      ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    777    ║ 111_777 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       3      ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ 2.00  ║    3   ║   777   ║    111    ║ 111_777 ║      1      ║ This is where the repeated  ║       1       ║                          ║       3      ║                              ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║ interaction b/w 111 and 777 ║               ║                          ║              ║                              ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║ happened                    ║               ║                          ║              ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ 2.00  ║    3   ║   111   ║    333    ║ 111_333 ║      0      ║                             ║       0       ║                          ║       1      ║                              ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║  2.00 ║    3   ║   111   ║    777    ║ 111_777 ║      1      ║ This is where the repeated  ║       2       ║ This is where the second ║       3      ║ In total, 111 and 777 had    ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║ interaction b/w 111 and 777 ║               ║ 'repeated interaction'   ║              ║ 3 interactions in the thread ║
║       ║        ║         ║           ║         ║             ║ happened                    ║               ║ occurred                 ║              ║                              ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is ordered correctly:

```
dat <- structure(list(topic = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), thread = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), speaker_id = c(111, 111, 333, 
222, 222, 222, 111, 111, 777, 111, 111), recipient_id = c(222, 
333, 111, 111, 555, 444, 222, 777, 111, 333, 777), dyad = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("111_222", 
"111_333", "111_777", "222_444", "222_555"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), codepage = 51949L)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(dyad, thread) %>% #level of analysis
  mutate(`Repeated Interaction (1/0)` = as.numeric(duplicated(dyad)),
         `Repeated Interaction (order)` = cumsum(`Repeated Interaction (1/0)`),
         `Total Interactions` = n()
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

You want to know if they interact a second time (`duplicated()`), how many times they interact after the first (how many `duplicated()`, so a cumulative sum `cumsum()`) and finally how many total interactions (`n()`), all at the `dyad-thread` level.